# Understanding solution to the Optimal Account Balancing (Leetcode 465) in python

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, bit-manipulation, dynamic-programming, recursive-backtracking

The problem can be accessed from this link
https://leetcode.com/problems/optimal-account-balancing/

*** Didn't realize this was only accessible by premium members, here is the problem statement and examples***

You are given an array of transactions transactions where transactions[i] = [fromi, toi, amounti] indicates that the person with ID = fromi gave amounti $ to the person with ID = toi.

Return the minimum number of transactions required to settle the debt.

Example 1:

```
Input: transactions = [[0,1,10],[2,0,5]]
Output: 2
Explanation:
Person #0 gave person #1 $10.
Person #2 gave person #0 $5.
Two transactions are needed. One way to settle the debt is person #1 pays person #0 and #2 $5 each.
```

Example 2:

```
Input: transactions = [[0,1,10],[1,0,1],[1,2,5],[2,0,5]]
Output: 1
Explanation:
Person #0 gave person #1 $10.
Person #1 gave person #0 $1.
Person #1 gave person #2 $5.
Person #2 gave person #0 $5.
Therefore, person #1 only need to give person #0 $4, and all debt is settled.
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= transactions.length <= 8
transactions[i].length == 3
0 <= fromi, toi < 12
fromi != toi
1 <= amounti <= 100
```

Questions

The first thing is, I am trying to understand how the dp function inside works. I don't use use bitwise operation too much but am vaguely familiar with what shifting, ^(Xor), and mask does but in this example, I'm having a hard time of putting them together.

Secondly, maybe I'll have a better idea once I understand the first problem. However if you could shed some light on what it's memoizing, the time complexity, and how that is more optimal, that would be awesome.

Thirdly, I have come up with my solution to this problem which is at the bottom of this post. I used plain backtracking but when it comes to analyzing the time complexity, I am slightly uncertain. My intuition is that since for loop inside the 'backtrack' function is going from 0 -> len(balance) then 1-> len(balance) ... so it'd be O(n^2)? (if we assume n = len(balance)). Correct me if I am wrong.

Truly thank you for your help in advance.

```
class Solution:
    def minTransfers(self, T: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        p = [0] * 12
        for f,t,a in T:
            p[f] -= a
            p[t] += a
        arr = []
        for a in p:
            if a != 0:
                arr.append(a)
        memo = {}
        def dp(count, cur, mask):
            nonlocal memo
            if (count, cur, mask) in memo:
                return memo[(count, cur, mask)]
            if mask == 0:
                return 0
            res = inf
            for i in range(len(arr)):
                if (1<<i)&mask:
                    if cur+arr[i]==0:
                        res = min(res, dp(0, 0, (1<<i)^mask)+count)
                    else:
                        res = min(res, dp(count+1, cur+arr[i], (1<<i)^mask))
            memo[(count, cur, mask)] = res
            return res
        mask = (1<<len(arr))-1
        return dp(0,0,mask)
```

My solution

```
class Solution:
    def minTransfers(self, transactions: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        # hash person giving and receiving money 

        map = {}

        for i in transactions:
            map[i[0]] = map.get(i[0],0)-i[2]
            map[i[1]] = map.get(i[1],0)+i[2]
        
        balance = [] 
        for key,val in map.items():
            if val != 0:
                balance.append(val)
        
        def backtrack(idx):
            if idx == len(balance):
                return 0 
            
            if balance[idx] == 0:
                return backtrack(idx+1)
            
            result = float('inf')

            for curr in range(idx+1,len(balance)):
                
                if balance[idx]*balance[curr] < 0:
                    balance[curr]+= balance[idx]
                    result = min(result,1+backtrack(idx+1))
                    balance[curr]-= balance[idx]
            return result 
        
        return backtrack(0)
```

Comment: *"first..., secondly..., thirdly..."*: A question on Stack Overflow should be limited to one question only, and should be focused. Also, *"Trying to understand"*, *"shed some light"*, *"I'm slightly uncertain"* ..etc are not very clear questions; in fact they are not questions to begin with.  Choose one thing to ask about and make it very concrete what exactly need clarification.

Comment: Visiting the link, it says I must be a premium subscriber to view. Please explain the task the code is solving. (Links generally are unreliable since they can expire.)

Comment: My bad, I updated the question @גלעד ברקן

Answer (score 0):

`mask` is keeping track of which accounts still need to be settled by setting a bit for those accounts.

```py
if cur+arr[i]==0:
  res = min(res, dp(0, 0, (1<<i)^mask)+count)
...
```

is saying essentially "if the current amount settles the `i`th account, let's try settling it to see if `res`, which is keeping track of the least transactions needed, can be made smaller." `(1<<i)^mask` unsets the bit in the mask keeping track of whether the `i`th account has a balance.

The solution space, which is more-or-less the time and space complexity of the `dp` recursion, is `O(count * curr * 2^num_accounts)`, where `count` is the maximum number of transactions and `curr` is the maximum amount tracked.

(I did not attempt to review the complexity of your solution.)